# Reading XML in table

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a stored procedure which is passed XML as a parameter and then I have to read that xML and do some updates. The format of the XML is

```xml
<Requests>
    <RequestReference>R12345</RequestReference>
    <Inventory InventoryId="1" InventoryName="I1">
        <RequestCodes>
            <Code>AAA</Code>
        </RequestCodes>
    </Inventory>
    <Inventory InventoryId="2" InventoryName="I2">
        <RequestCodes>
            <Code>BBB</Code>
            <Code>CCC</Code>
        </RequestCodes>
    </Inventory>
    <Inventory InventoryId="3" InventoryName="I3">
        <RequestCodes>
            <Code>DDD</Code>
            <Code>EEE</Code>
            <Code>FFF</Code>
        </RequestCodes>
    </Inventory>
</Requests>
```

Now I need to read the XML in a table like

```
RequestReference    InventoryId InventoryName           Code
R12345                    1           I1            AAA
R12345                    2           I2            BBB
R12345                    2           I2            CCC
R12345                    3           I3            DDD
R12345                    3           I3            EEE
R12345                    3           I3            FFF
```

I am trying something like

```sql
SELECT 
    T.Item.value('@InventoryId', 'VARCHAR(3)')  AS InventoryId,
    T.Item.value('@InventoryName', 'VARCHAR(3)')    AS InventoryName,
    T.Item.value('RequestCodes[1]/Code[1]', 'VARCHAR(5)')   AS Code
FROM   
   @xmlDoc.nodes('Requests/Inventory') 
   AS T(Item)
```

The result which it produced is

```
InventoryId InventoryName   Code
1                 I1    AAA
2                 I2    BBB
3                 I3    DDD
```

So this seems to be working but not producing the desired results completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
select *
from
(
SELECT
    T.Item.value('../../../RequestReference[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')  AS RequestReference,
    T.Item.value('../../@InventoryId', 'VARCHAR(3)')  AS InventoryId,
    T.Item.value('../../@InventoryName', 'VARCHAR(3)')    AS InventoryName,
    T.Item.value('.', 'VARCHAR(5)')   AS Code
FROM   
   @xmlDoc.nodes('//Code') 
   AS T(Item)
)t
order by InventoryId, InventoryName, Code
```

Comment: I never really thought of backtracing the XML nodes.

Answer (score 2):

try this.You can use either outer or cross apply

```
select
--ref.query('.'),
rr.rr.value('(.)[1]','varchar(20)') as RequestReference,
--inv.inv.query('.'),
inv.inv.value('(./@InventoryId)[1]','int') as InventoryId ,
inv.inv.value('(./@InventoryName)[1]','Varchar(20)') as InventoryName ,
rc.rc.value('(.)[1]','varchar(20)') as Codes
from 
@xml.nodes('Requests') rq(ref)
cross apply rq.ref.nodes('./Inventory') inv(inv)
cross apply inv.inv.nodes('./RequestCodes/Code') rc(rc)
cross apply rq.ref.nodes('./RequestReference') rr(rr)
```